# What environment would Giants be best adapted for?

Tags: science-based, environment, fantasy-races

In my story [Giants](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/168747/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-capture-a-giant?noredirect=1&lq=1), humans, and a bunch of other [fantasy races](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/168595/why-would-humans-be-the-dominant-species) live along side each other and i'm curious as to what sort of environment (on earth) would best suit them? some basic characteristics of my Giants include:

- 10.5ft (3.2 m) tall and weigh 619lbs (280kg)
- have bloodhound level sense of smell and greatly improved hearing
- have thick skin approaching 0.5 in (12.7 mm) at its thickest
- have Human-level intelligence
- are proportionately weaker than a human (but are still quite strong)
- have worse endurance
- can't jump
- are surprisingly good swimmers

Note: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: What does "best" mean for you here in this context? Please be more specific.

Comment: @kleer001 "best" in this case means most acclimated to

Comment: looking at elephant probably rainforest and savannah, or if you want something like [gigantopithecus](https://i0.wp.com/cdn.sci-news.com/images/2011/11/image_74.jpg) then its bamboo forest, or in the ocean like whale.

Comment: oh yeah theres also [Meganthropus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meganthropus) (prehistoric giant human) which live in java island in prehistoric era which as far as i know is tropical/rainforest.

Comment: @LiJun really? never here of Meganthropus before.

Comment: they live bordered with homo floresiensis  which is the eastern part of java islands or flores island. [here the image height difference between it](https://alchetron.com/cdn/meganthropus-760761d2-8a9b-4dd9-96fb-b27084582c7-resize-750.jpeg), but i dont know what lead them to be giant, or is this prehistoric human is still valid today or not.

Comment: @LiJun god it's so surreal know that the largest hominid lived in the general area as the smallest hominid

Comment: @LiJun also i'm surprised by how little information there is on they were compared to homo floresiensis or gigantopithecus. maybe it's their isn't enough valid info on it?

Comment: yeah seems so, there some debatable about it as far as i know, iam not archelogist or an expert of this though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "surprisingly good swimmers" suggested that they are semi-aquatic. There are human ethnic groups that [arguably count as such](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sama-Bajau).

Using that as model they would travel in ships along the coasts and maybe rivers and get their food by diving and fishing.

Being large would not only be less of an issue when swimming or diving due to buoyancy, it would help with the thick skin in retaining body heat so giants could dive in waters where humans would just die.

Improved sense of smell and hearing would allow detecting things from longer distances. You could smell land and hear each other from a distance. This would be especially useful when swimming with significant waves since you would not need to see over the waves to find your friends. Additionally these senses could reasonably work underwater where they are generally more useful than vision. Especially if the water is mostly brown as with many rivers.

Apart from helping retain heat if you swim in cold waters the thick skin would also protect you from various parasites and small wounds that would get infected in water. It would also in general stand up better to water than human thin skin.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if can fit perfectly but...

**Born on Mars!**

With 38% of Earth's gravity, their bodies will grow more, proportionally within the square cube law.

The time for the heart to pump blood to a much larger body and for the electrical signals from the brain go to the extremes will make them have slower reflexes, this is enough to be weak but not so much.

Because they are, well, humans born in different conditions, they have no cognitive differences.

Thick skin can happen thanks to frequent Martian sandstorms.

Being from a world with less atmospheric pressure, hearing and smell are much more sensitive in the Earth's atmosphere.

The difficulty in moving at first in the conditions of the Earth has accustomed us to living in water most of the time, [like whales](https://www.earthmagazine.org/article/how-amphibious-whales-returned-sea).

Another thing to add: a bigger body will, of course, have a bigger skull and the brain inside will have more room. There is a [relationship between neuronal density and sleep time](https://jeb.biologists.org/content/219/3/299). Since these giants will have roughly the same 16 billion neurons in the prefrontal cortex but have a much larger surface area to distribute them, they will have a much shorter sleep time. Unless they are short of food.

Comment: should have been more clear with it being on earth sorry. but other than that interesting answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

Savannah would be a good bet

Most thing there will have a hard time bothering them.

Being tall is better for hot weather but a detriment in cold weather.

They don't have human endurance but a better sense of smell makes for good scavengers (and better at finding water) plus they can can probably throw a stone with enough force to kill many creatures, they could huck a spear a huge distance, so hunting is a possibility, and the mixed vegetation would let them sneak up on some creatures.

Large size will also help them conserve water in dry environments.

*things they will be bad at.*

1. Most forests are right out, big size and dense vegetation is not a good mix.
2. Mountains, tall bipeds and mountains just begging for lethal fall.
3. swamps being big and bipedal is not good is a swamp, swamp soil is soft so you need to disperse the weight as much as possible. Plus swamps contain one predator giants with have a hard time with, crocodiles which are ambush predators.