# What environment would Orcs be best adapted for?

Tags: science-based, environment, fantasy-races

In my story [Orcs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167531/what-evolutionary-pressures-would-lead-to-orcs), humans, and a bunch of other [fantasy races](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/168595/why-would-humans-be-the-dominant-species) live along side each other and i'm curious as to what sort of environment (on earth) would best suit them? so basic characteristics of my Orcs include:

- Can range in height from 161.5 cm (5 ft 3 in) to 188.9 cm (6 ft 2 in) tall
- Are as intelligent as humans
- Are two times stronger than humans but spend more time resting (not necessarily sleeping)
- Have a mildly improved sense of smell
- Are gray in coloration
- are surprisingly good swimmers

Note: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: Impossible to tell with this info. It would depend on evolutionary factors. I guess you could say this is essentially a dupe of your previous question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I immediately thought of an arctic environment due to their natural coloration and swimming abilities.

Some other ideas I have are:

1. Freshwater Coastal: pearl,coral,exotic fish farming. Similar to Japan, The Galapagos, Hawaii
2. Tropical Rainforest: Height for climbing, swimming ability for rivers and lakes, and smell for survival, hunting, etc...
3. Flatlands: Raise cattle, farm, etc...
4. Mountanious: Hunt wildlife, mine, provide protection and safe trade routes for merchants and travelers (as they travel along Orc built highways, roads, bridges, ...) in exchange for money, food, needed resources, etc...
5. Traveling merchants: Have different clans or families who migrate/caravan different routes which always have (all or some of) the Orcs converging (any number of years) at different cities, towns, or at special places of the Orc people.

Comment: Oh! another thing: Height isn't always a disadvantage. Small/short people can go places larger/taller people can't. It may make time for them to reach (lets say food up in the tree) but they could be expert scavengers and skilled with things such as shaping the roots of trees into homes and secret spaces hidden to the naked eye.

Comment: Smaller size also means less need for food.

Answer (score 0):

In the novel series of Sellswords by R. A. Salvatore of Forgotten Realms, there is a town called Palishchuk. This village has half-orcs both as characters with an orcish seeming masculine body or more human-like graceful conduct. The folk of this particular village has strong trade business relations with other towns. They have all sorts of sages, priests, mages, aristocrats. Maybe this unique town was an intro to the age of the orcs in the Forgotten Realms.

The state of the town in the books was around (maybe just before?) Obould Many-Arrows's great war and which have changed the realms a lot, thus orcs have been granted some rights that they formerly not had, such as; ability to trade with other civilizations, to be a crime to kill an orc just as other races are, to be presented at regional congresses... And these events eventually brought about the end of hatred towards orcs and vice verse. A decent lifestyle contributed to develop the orc community and customs. Then they prove to be just skilled in magic and other professions just as humans or dwarves do.

> And also turns out orcs had an ancient civilization much similar lifestyle as dwarves have beneath the Silver Marches. In this ancient civilization of orcs, there were masonry, pottery, and monuments such as dwarves do and living grounds in many meters below ground. So the old orcs liked mining and digging just as dwarves do.

Summary: Orcs and other wretched creatures could be politically strong just as other civilizations do. They could have a rich community and they'd like to be respected. They might attend to more labor work than the average folk because they are more masculine but they are just as intelligent as others.

Ref:

https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Promise_of_the_Witch-King
https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hunter%27s_Blades_Trilogy
https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Treaty_of_Garumn%27s_Gorge

Comment: ok orcs in my world have just as mighty civilizations as any other race. what i want to know is in a world with high competition where might the early orc settlements be inclined to live at